# SSIS/SQL Server - Flag based on multiple condition columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have following table:

```
 ID | Number | Condition 1 | Condition 2 | Condition 3 | Condition 4 
 1  | 1      | 1           | 2           | 1           | 1
 1  | 2      | 2           | 1           | 2           | 2
 2  | 5      | 2           | 2           | 2           | 1
 2  | 6      | 2           | 2           | 2           | 2
 3  | 7      | 1           | 1           | 2           | 1
 3  | 8      | 2           | 1           | 1           | 2
 3  | 3      | 2           | 1           | 2           | 2
 4  | 9      | 2           | 1           | 1           | 1
 4  | 4      | 1           | 1           | 1           | 2
 5  | 10     | 2           | 1           | 2           | 1
 5  | 13     | 2           | 1           | 2           | 2
```

(Quite confusion, sorry about that)

As you can see, there are multiple IDs. I have to take one of each ID, based on the conditions. So, I want to check each condition one by one and add a column based on the result in my output. The logic behind this is

> if (for each group of ID's) one row has `condition` = 1 then that's the correct one. If both rows are 1 or both are 2, then we check the following condition.

So, If we take only the records with `ID 1`, we can see the `ID 1 - Number 1` is the correct one we need in our output.

But if we take `ID 2`, we see that both records have the same value, which doesn't give us an answer. In that case, we look at `condition 2` and implement the same logic there.

(`condition 4` will ALWAYS have one record with '1' for each ID)

So my output would be:

```
 ID | Number | Condition 1 | Condition 2 | Condition 3 | Condition 4 | IsOk
 1  | 1      | 1           | 2           | 1           | 1           | 1
 1  | 2      | 2           | 1           | 2           | 2           | 2
 2  | 5      | 2           | 2           | 2           | 1           | 1
 2  | 6      | 2           | 2           | 2           | 2           | 2
 3  | 7      | 1           | 1           | 2           | 1           | 1
 3  | 8      | 2           | 1           | 1           | 2           | 2
 3  | 3      | 2           | 1           | 2           | 2           | 2
 4  | 9      | 2           | 1           | 1           | 1           | 2
 4  | 4      | 1           | 1           | 1           | 2           | 1
 5  | 10     | 2           | 1           | 2           | 1           | 1
 5  | 13     | 2           | 1           | 2           | 2           | 2
```

Any advice/Suggestions?

I will be using this in SSIS, so solutions in SSIS or pure SQL code are all OK for me.

In case someone wonders: I tried it with `Case`

```
  ,CASE
   when [Condition1] = 1 then 1
    else CASE when [Condition2] = 1 then 1 
     else   CASE when [Condition3] = 1 then 1 
        else        CASE when [Condition4] = 1 then 1 END
        END
        END
   END AS IsOk
```

But that didn't give the requested result

Comment: Will your `Condition` values always be `1` or `2` or are they just examples of more complex data?

Comment: They will always be `1` or `2`. It's just another way to say `true` / `fasle` in this case

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about the use case for this table?  It looks like you are starting on a Junk Dimension table or a Flags table where the second has only bits in each column.

Comment: Also, should "IsOk" only equal 1 for one row for each Id?  Id number 3 above has two rows with IsOk equals 1.

Comment: @Michaelbuller It's actually a view I made on a large table (which you could call a dimension). The conditions are based on `cases` such as: `Case when Category LIKE 'Series3%' then 1 else 0 End AS Condition1`.

Also, that IsOk can only be 1 for one row of each ID (as you said). I edited my mistake (my excuses for that)

Comment: Well it looks like you are actually comparing different rows against each other to evaluate which one has a true flag earliest in the list of conditions.  You will have to use some recursion to do that.  I would think a CTE joining on the Id = Id, then you can evaluate the conditions at the same time.

Comment: @Michaelbuller  Thanks to the preference and consistent ordering of the `Condition` values recursion is not required, just a self referential derived table, per my answer below.

Comment: You are doing exactly what I described, and by using a CTE you are being recursive in that you are referencing CTE twice below. `from cte c1
    left join cte c2
        on(c1.ID = c2.ID
            and c1.rn = c2.rn+1
            )`  I would say you answered correctly, just making sure our semantics are the same.

Comment: @Michaelbuller  Semantically I would agree, but personally - and I would imagine others do to - I reserve the word 'recursion' in SQL Server specifically for recursive CTEs, for ease of understanding and explanation.

Comment: And why do you say you are not using a recursive CTE below?

Comment: @Michaelbuller  Because the derived table creation isn't self referential ie: with a `union` to build the table row by row based on previous row values.  As I say, semantically I agree that a table that refers to itself is recursive, but you could just as easily do what I did below without a `cte` by just inserting into a temp table.  I would call something like this https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/ a recursive `cte` as it is its own particular thing, that does a specific job and is commonly known as a recursive `cte`.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Dave.  I am glad you cleared that up for me.  So no recursion in that the CTE isn't being referenced inside of the view definition aka referencing itself.  I had it in my mind that a window function used inside the view definition, then using that to filter the second view was recursion, where it in fact is not.  Really that is just two views being joined together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a self referential derived table.  Essentially, you check whether each row would be independently 'Ok' and then join that dataset to itself to check if a previous row was already deemed 'Ok', in which case mark it as 'Not Ok'.  This works because your conditions are always `1` or `2` so when creating the `row_number` you can order in preference of `Condition` and which will guarantee that the 'first' row to be 'Ok' will have the preferential `row_number` ie: You won't get any cases of an 'Ok' row being returned with a higher `row_number` than a 'Not Ok' row for the same `ID`:

```
declare @t table(ID int
                ,Number int
                ,Condition1 int
                ,Condition2 int
                ,Condition3 int
                ,Condition4 int
                );
insert into @t values
 (1,1,1,2,1,1)
,(1,2,2,1,2,2)
,(2,5,2,2,2,1)
,(2,6,2,2,2,2)
,(3,7,1,1,2,1)
,(3,8,2,1,1,2)
,(3,3,2,1,2,2)
,(4,9,2,1,1,1)
,(4,4,1,1,1,2)
,(5,10,2,1,2,1)
,(5,13,2,1,2,2);


with cte as
(
    select row_number() over (order by ID
                                    ,Condition1
                                    ,Condition2
                                    ,Condition3
                                    ,Condition4
                            ) as rn
            ,ID
            ,Number
            ,Condition1
            ,Condition2
            ,Condition3
            ,Condition4
            ,case when Condition1 = 1 then 1
                else case when Condition2 = 1 then 1
                    else case when Condition3 = 1 then 1
                        else case when Condition4 = 1 then 1
                            else 2
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end as IsOk
    from @t
)
select c1.ID
        ,c1.Number
        ,c1.Condition1
        ,c1.Condition2
        ,c1.Condition3
        ,c1.Condition4
        ,case when isnull(c2.IsOk,0) = 1 then 2 else c1.IsOk end as IsOk
from cte c1
    left join cte c2
        on(c1.ID = c2.ID
            and c1.rn = c2.rn+1
            )
order by c1.rn;
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, Thank you very much!